# Python - BeautifulSoup : Scraping a tag with "data-obfuscated=true"

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this [tag](http://prntscr.com/h2byqw) through:

```
forum = soup.find('a', {'class': 'linkLabel__1VsFan'})
print (forum)
```

But it return me none, do you think it's caused by the `data-obfuscated="true"` ? Because it's the first time I have a problem to parse an entire tag and the first time I encounter this (data-obfuscated).

Entire code :

```
import re    
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requete = requests.get("http://www.jeuxvideo.com/tous-les-jeux/")
page = requete.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
forum = soup.find_all('a', {'class': re.compile('^linkLabel')})
print (forum)
```

'a' html tag :

```
<a href="/forums/0-3011046-0-1-0-1-0-fifa-18.htm" data-obfuscated="true" class="linkLabel__1VsFan" data-reactid="505">Forum</a>
```

Comment: Looks like you are viewing the tag in dev tools in a browser. How does it looks in a cURL request (or something like that)? It could be that the tag content for tags with `data-obfuscated` is rendered or loaded via JS after page load or something similar.

Comment: No he is not, the tag still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Basically look for elements with class starting with `linkLabel`:

```
import re
soup.find('a', {'class': re.compile('^linkLabel')})
```

The thing on the right `1VsFan` is generated randomly (possibly by [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)) and can change unpredictably whenever the website changes. Don't rely on it.

Also make sure the website you're trying to scrape has server-side rendering (open it with a browser and `View Source`). If the tag you're looking for is not there, it may mean that the page is rendered inside the browser using JavaScript. If this is the case, you'll need to use a real JavaScript-capable browser to scrape it (headless Chrome will probably work for you, also have a look at the [`splinter`](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for Python for controlling browsers).

The `data-` attributes are just normal attributes that Javascript code can pick up. They shouldn't confuse beautifulsoup in any way.

Comment: I've check, the tag is same in the [source code](http://prntscr.com/h2cex4) but your code is not working, still returning me empty list.

Comment: I can further help if you provide a self contained python snippet that includes the string literal like `soup = BeautifulSoup(...actual html code...)`

Comment: The html returned by that page is huge but I can only see thinks like `<span class="linkLabel__1VsFan" data-reactid="925">`, no `a`

Comment: Yeah but there is also `a` tag with this class

Comment: Checking by hand with regexes I can see 106 occurrences of `linkLabel`: 6 in the CSS spreadsheet and 100 in `<span` tags

Comment: If you open the page in a browser, `<a` tags are added with JavaScript, but they are not in the source

Comment: Yeah but when I replace `a` by `span` tag in my code, the `href` content which I was looking for is not here

Comment: I think it disappear because of the `data-obfuscated` set to `true`